# error: C2065: 'DBL_MAX' : undeclared identifier (in VS2008 but not in VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

In my code I use `DBL_MAX`, which is defined in math.h. In VS2010 it works fine, but in VS2008 I get an error:

```
error: C2065: 'DBL_MAX' : undeclared identifier
```

Is DBL_MAX available in VS2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was being dumb, I should have checked the actual header - it's in float.h, not math.h. It seems that math.h includes float.h in VS2010 but not in VS2008.

What confused me was that it was working in VS2010, so I just assumed DBL_MAX it's not available for VS2008.

So adding it fixed the issue:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
```

I'm posting this in case anyone else ever makes the same mistake.